# Merging more than one rdlc into single reportviewer control

Tags: c#

I want to merge 2 *.rdlc* files (with C#) into a single *.rdlc* so that it prints in a single file in reportviewer control.

This is what I'm trying:

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "model1.rdlc";
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "model2.rdlc";

this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

but it's only showing me the second report (*model2.rdlc*)

Comment: The second line of code is setting ReportPath and then third line of code is also setting ReportPath so 2nd line of code is doing nothing.  You after 2nd line of code to add data to the reportViewer before changing the ReportPath.

Comment: An rdlc file is an xml document which defines a report. You can't necessarily just merge two reports. They may have very different structures. What if they're pulling from different tables, or are pulling different columns from the same tables?

Comment: Can you give more information on why you are trying to do this.

Comment: You can use subreports. See: [Subreport in RDLC file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349546/subreport-in-rdlc-file)

Comment: Or you can add two report viewers in the same container

Answer (score 0):

Reportviewer show's just one report file at time

because you overwrite the report path at the second line
it behaves like that (showing the last report)

You have some options:

1- Using subreport inside the first report and setting the supreport parameter as report 2.

2- Using multiple data sourses for one report and merge the two reports in the report.

3- Using the page brake option to split your report to multiple pages but it has some limitation because of it cannot work at any area unless it has a container in the report like (table - rectangle - matrix).